# Substituir valor null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de que quando viesse *null* no meu select substituísse por `1900`, segue select:

```
SELECT   
(SELECT TOP 1 tabela1.data
       FROM tabela1 tabela1
      WHERE tabela1.id = tabela2.id) as data
       FROM tabela2 tabela2
```

Comment: O exemplo a seguir localiza a média do peso de todos os produtos. Substitui o valor 50 para todas as entradas NULL na coluna Weight da tabela **SELECT AVG(ISNULL(Weight, 50)) FROM Production.Product;**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como falado na outra resposta, use o **[ISNULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)**, mas desta forma:

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (SELECT TOP 1 tabela1.data 
       FROM tabela1 tabela1 
       WHERE tabela1.id = tabela2.id), '1900') as data 
FROM tabela2 tabela2
```

detalhe: você também pode fazer esta consulta usando `join`, acho que ficaria mais simples:

```
SELECT ISNULL(tabela1.data, '1900')
FROM tabela1 
JOIN tabela2 on tabela1.id = tabela2.id
```

Answer (score 4):

Só usar o **ISNULL**

```
SELECT ISNULL(tabela1.data,'1900')   

(SELECT TOP 1 tabela1.data
   FROM tabela1 tabela1
  WHERE tabela1.id = tabela2.id) as data
   FROM tabela2 tabela2
```

Comment: Coloque a resposta de forma funcional. Para melhor entendimento.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o help on-line do [SQL-Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql), você pode usar a função **ISNULL**.

**Sintaxe do comando**

`ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`

**Por tanto o seu select ficaria assim:**

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (SELECT TOP 1 tabela1.data 
FROM tabela1 tabela1 
WHERE tabela1.id = tabela2.id), '1900') as data 
FROM tabela2 tabela2
```